# Compare List value of different types

Tags: java

I am trying to compare a list of type Car that has no equals method.

Car.java

```
public class Car {
    private int carNumber;
    private String carName;

    public Car(int carNumber, String carName)
    {
        super();
        this.carNumber = carNumber;
        this.carName = carName;
    }

    /**
     * @return The carNumber.
     */
    public int getCarNumber()
    {
        return carNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @param carNumber The carNumber to set.
     */
    public void setCarNumber(int carNumber)
    {
        this.carNumber = carNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @return The carName.
     */
    public String getCarName()
    {
        return carName;
    }

    /**
     * @param carName The carName to set.
     */
    public void setCarName(String carName)
    {
        this.carName = carName;
    } }
```

Main class :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListCar
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Car carList1_a = new Car(1, "Camry");
        Car carList1_b = new Car(2, "Corolla");
        Car carList1_d = new Car(3, "BMW");

        Car carList2_d = new Car(3, "BMW");
        Car carList2_a = new Car(2, "Corolla");
        Car carList2_b = new Car(1, "Camry");

        List<Car> carList1 = new ArrayList<Car>();
        carList1.add(carList1_a);
        carList1.add(carList1_b);
        carList1.add(carList1_d);

        List<Car> carList2 = new ArrayList<Car>();
        carList2.add(carList2_b);
        carList2.add(carList2_d);
        carList2.add(carList2_a);

        System.out.println(compareLists(carList1, carList2));
    }
public static boolean compareLists(List<Car> prevList, List<Car> modelList) 
{
    if (prevList!= null && modelList!=null && prevList.size() == modelList.size()) 
    {
        boolean indicator = false;
        for (Car modelListdata : modelList) 
        {
            for (Car prevListdata : prevList) 
            {
                if (prevListdata.getCarName().equals(modelListdata.getCarName()) && prevListdata.getCarNumber() == modelListdata.getCarNumber()) 
                {
                    return  true;
                }
                if (modelListdata.getCarName().equals(prevListdata.getCarName())) 
                {
                    indicator = false;
                    break;
                } 
                else
                {
                    indicator = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (indicator)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false; 
}
}
```

The above method compareLists() does not compare the entire list , I am looking to improvise the method to compare each element of the list of Car type regardless of the order. Without equals method in the Car class.

Any input would be helpful

Thanks !!!

Comment: What do you mean: `compare lists` ? Do you want to check if both lists are equal? In that case why do you return `true` (equals) when lists have different sizes?

Comment: Yes, I want to compare the list. Thanks for catching that , I have removed that else block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate the first List and check that every element is in the second list. If you found an element not found in the second list, the lists are different.

The implementation could be:

```
public static boolean compareLists(List<Car> prevList, List<Car> modelList) 
{
    boolean listEquals = true;
    if (prevList!= null && modelList!=null && prevList.size() == modelList.size()) 
    {
        for (Car modelListdata : modelList) 
        {
            boolean elementInList = false;
            for (Car prevListdata : prevList) 
            {
                if (prevListdata.getCarName().equals(modelListdata.getCarName()) && prevListdata.getCarNumber() == modelListdata.getCarNumber()) 
                {
                    /* The list has the element, set the flag to true and break the loop */ 
                    elementInList = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (elementInList == false) {
                /* There is one element not found in the second list, the lists are not equals */
                listEquals = false;
                break;
            }
        }            
        return listEquals;
    } else {
        /* At least one list is null or the size is not the same */
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you implement the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods in your Car class, the code is much more simple as you could use the `contains()` method of the list:

```
public static boolean compareListsEquals(List<Car> prevList, List<Car> modelList) 
{
    if (prevList!= null && modelList!=null && prevList.size() == modelList.size()) 
    {
        for (Car modelListdata : modelList) 
        {
            if (prevList.contains(modelListdata) == false) {
                return false;
            }
        }            
        return true;
    } else {
        /* At least one list is null or the size is not the same */
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if that `return true` is a smart thing to do.

[EDIT]

Ok, since it smells like homework I just wanted to give a hint... but here it comes the spoon.

The answer from David is pretty good so I won't reiterate the answer. No pun intended.

Comment: Where in exactly , and how it helps to iterate through the entire list.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if lists are equal without using equal method for car, then you should:
**1. Stop using iterators.**
You should be comparing first element with first element. Second with second etc.
You need to use element at the same position in both lists.
It will work given that if lists have different number of elements - it will not be equal.
Using iterators is problematic for that.
**2. Check only for `not equal` elements** - in that case `return false`.
**3. At the end of algorithm `return true`** - when each element was checked and passed.
**4.** Be sure you correctly handles cases with different sizes of list (return false) or when one of them is null (return false) or when both are null (return true).

I hope that helps. Let me know if you need more detailed version with some example.

Comment: I am looking for something that helps to compare the list even if the order of the list element are different. Something like list (1,2,3) compare with list(1,3,2) return true.

Comment: So you have to check first if they have the same number of elements. (see point 4.) You are doing it at the moment. If not - return not equal (false) and don't process anything.